# Qt C++ no match for 'operator<<' stream

Tags: c++, qt

Basically I made a simple function in QT C++ to write the variable "name" onto a .txt file, however whenever I compile I get a error message of:

```
no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are
'QTextStream' and 'std::string 
{aka std::basic_string<char>}')
         stream << name;
```

I've looked over the line a bunch of times but I don't know whats going on, any input on my error would be greatly appreciated.

Function Code:

```
void Write()
{
    std::string name;
    QFile file("C:/Users/brandan/Desktop/GUIPrograms/Kumon.txt");

    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file); //stream of information
        stream << name;

        stream.flush();
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's absolutely no need to use `std::string` in Qt code, unless you're interfacing with third-party code that needs `std::string`. Use `QString`. It's as simple as that. You'll find that `QString` actually has an api that applies to many real-world use cases and make life comparably easy compared to gymnastics needed to deal with `std::string`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Qt stream classes don't handle `std::string` directly. You need to convert that to a `QString` to be able to use it with `QTextStream`.

For example:

```
stream << QString::fromStdString(name);
```

[`QString::fromStdString` docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html).

Or since `QTextStream`'s [`operator<<`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html#operator-lt-lt-16) has an overload for `const char*`, you could also do:

```
stream << name.c_str();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a `qt` person, but looks like there's [no overload](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html) for `std::string`

Use :

`stream << name.c_str();`